# Delay with event listeners through jQuery requirejs

Tags: magento2

Sometimes my event listeners work and the elements trigger the events, other times they do not. I believe it is due to a delay. However chrome states the page is fully loaded by the time. I'm clicking on elements. It is a matter of seconds, not milliseconds.

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
   $(window).load(function() {
       // Added event listeners here.
   });
});
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: try adding timeout - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252638/executing-javascript-after-x-seconds

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The solution worked for me after adding the js in function and calling that function.

```
function test() {
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            // Added event listeners here.
        });
    });
}
```

For example if you are using the **Carousel**. I created the delay of one second then I don't face this issue.

```
function slider() {
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($) {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#banner_slider").owlCarousel({
                navigation: false,
                slideSpeed: 300,
                paginationSpeed: 400,
                singleItem: true,
                pagination: true,
                rewindSpeed: 500
            });
            window.clearTimeout();
        });
    });
}
setTimeout(slider, 1000);
```